# Remove braces in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove the braces so "{test}" becomes "test".
I tried

```
"{test}".gsub(/\{(.*)\}/,$1)
while "{test}".gsub!(/(\{).*(\})/,""); end
"{test}".gsub(/\{.*\}/,"")
```

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `\1`, not `$1`

```
"{test}".gsub /\{(.*)\}/, '\1'
```

Or, if you just want to delete all curly braces:

```
"{test}".delete "{}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to remove all curly brackets from a given statement. In that case please try

```
"{test}".gsub(/\{|\}/, '')   => "test"
```

On the other hand if you want to remove curly brackets from the beginning or the hand you can perhaps do it using a non-regex based way

Answer (score 1):

You could use the delete function.

```
           static VALUE
rb_str_delete(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE str)
{
str = rb_str_dup(str);
rb_str_delete_bang(argc, argv, str);
return str;
 }
        example:
"hello".delete "l" =>"heo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **[String#tr](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)**

```
> "{test}".tr '{}', ''
#=> "test"
```